# Are there any plans for Docs.SO to come to some of the other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, documentation-beta

In my opinion, maybe SF, Unix.SE and SU could profit from Docs.SO quite well.

I suspect it could also be useful on at least some of the non IT-related sites.

From another point of view, there are some extra features which exist only on SO (jobs, +2 new review queues, etc). So maybe Docs.SO is planned as an SO-only extra feature, too.

It is also possible, that the core communities of some sites simply won't need such an extension.

Comment: (as always, improvements are welcomed, especially the grammar/spelling ones)

Comment: We are having a similar discussion at [meta.gis.se]: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/4273/115

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the comments section of the [announcement blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/):

> Filip Dupanović
>
> Can we expect to see documentation added in some form to other SE communities after it leaves beta?
>
> > [hairboat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165581/hairboat) (Mod) - replied to Filip Dupanović
> >
> > Possibly! As with Q&A, it's starting with programmers while we figure out how to make the feature the best thing it can be so it will last. At that point we'll consider branching it out to other communities as we did with the SE Q&A sites.

Also, by 'starting with programmers' they meant Stack Overflow, not Programmers.SE.

Comment: I won't build my hopes too high, e.g. Triage is on SO for quite a while, and still isn't enabled on any other site even though it appears to be a big success.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I feel the collective behavior of the SE a little bit contradictive in this matter: 1) They are continously extending the SE site network. 2) They commit every possible to leave the SO in a privilegized role even if it means the suppression of the other sites. It would be interesting to know, what is going really in the minds of the real bosses here, sometimes their acts seem a little bit self-mutilating to me.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with this - when reading IT-based sites such as Super User, there are several duplicates of explanations of similar methods, I would imagine the same applies to Server Fault, etc. Having documentation would provide a library for members (and anyone) to be able to refer to.

As for other sites; however, I am not too sure - there is a risk that documentation would take the form of Wikipedia-like pages, i.e. repeating in a large way of what is already out there. One exception is a list of reputable information sources as a form of documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I think, Wikipedia is far from being "ready" (as if the whole knowledge of the Humanity could be collected), even if you can read in it from _anything_, for example you can't really learn nuclear physics on it over a very beginner level. Writing these articles would be possible, but nobody did it until now. I suspect a similar future for the doc sites: after a point, writing really new content will be harder and harder.